# JSC_NON_GLOBAL_DEFINE_INIT_ERROR occurs when compiling js with Google Closure Compiler, webpack, and Firebase JS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack, google-closure-compiler

JSC_NON_GLOBAL_DEFINE_INIT_ERROR occurs when compiling js with tools below:

- webpack: 3.5.6
- Google Closure Compiler JS: 20170806.0.0
- Firebase JS SDK: 4.3.1

Environment

- MacOS X: 10.11.6
- node.js: v7.10.0
- npm: 4.2.0

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR in app.bundle.js:5325 (JSC_NON_GLOBAL_DEFINE_INIT_ERROR) @define variable  assignment must be global
```

with webpack.config.js like below:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ClosureCompiler({
      options: {
        languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
        languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT3',
        compilationLevel: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        warningLevel: 'QUIET'
      }
    })
  ]
```

This error would be due to the `@define` annotation inside [firebase/utils/constants.js](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/src/utils/constants.ts).

```
var CONSTANTS = exports.CONSTANTS = {
  /**
   * @define {boolean} Whether this is the client Node.js SDK.
   */
  NODE_CLIENT: false,
  /**
   * @define {boolean} Whether this is the Admin Node.js SDK.
   */
  NODE_ADMIN: false,
  /**
   * Firebase SDK Version
   */
  SDK_VERSION: '4.3.1'
};
```

I'm not sure well the reason why `Firebase` uses `@define` annotation, but I decided to use [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) as a tentative measure.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      output: {
        comments: false
      }
    }),
    new ClosureCompiler({
      options: {
        languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
        languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT3',
        compilationLevel: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        warningLevel: 'QUIET'
      }
    })
  ]
```

Fortunately UglifyjsWebpackPlugin seemed to fix this problem.

My questions are,

- Does anyone know a better way to solve this?
- Do you think there are any bad side-effects?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`@define` annotations must be global. In webpack, everything is a module and therefore it is not global.

Best option might be to write a custom loader that strips that annotation away.